# Cannot pass hidden form value to php

Tags: php, html, forms, hidden

When i pass the hidden value to the php file it gives (true) 1 as a answer.

I am passing the value from the modal to the php file.

The span value was retrieved using jquery.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php 
include "dbcon.php";
if(isset($_POST['pd_del']))
{
echo mysql_error();
$delid=isset($_POST['delidd']);
echo $delid;

}else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
 ?>
```

**HTML CODE:**

> Form thats send the product id to the php file

```
<form name="prd_del" action="del_prod.php" method="post">  
<div class="modal fade" id="delModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">DELETE PRODUCT</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Do you want to Delete this Product ??? <span id="delid" name="delid"></span></h5> 
        <input type="hidden" name="delidd" id="delid">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="pd_del" >Delete It!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with `id="delid"`

Comment: You have no (value="my value) in ( <input type="hidden" name="delidd" id="delid">). You also duplicated the id in the span ( <span id="delid" name="delid">)

Comment: So how can i pass the span value to php file ??

Comment: Could you show us your Javascript code?

Comment: What is the Value??? i dont see anything between the span

Comment: Here's the JS code..

$(document).on("click", ".product_delete", function () {
     var pd_del_id = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #delid").text( pd_del_id);
    $('#delModal').modal('show');
});

Comment: @Tasos The Value was the Particular Product Id

Comment: You should have edited your post to add the JS, would have been more clear. ;)

Comment: How can i edit @caCtus

Comment: Then add this to the jquery code ($("#delid").val(id);) -- id is the value variable you have for the span. then your hidden input will be (<input type="hidden" name="delidd" id="delid" value="">). Dont forget to change the spans id to something other than (delid). If this works ok ill put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML :

```
<h5>Do you want to Delete this Product ??? <span id="delid" name="delid"></span></h5> 
<input type="hidden" name="delidd" id="delid">
```

Your JS :

```
$(".modal-body #delid").text( pd_del_id);
```

First problem is that you have 2 elements with the same id value (the sppan and the input field). You shouldn't.

Change one of your ids, something like that :

```
<h5>Do you want to Delete this Product ??? <span id="delid" name="delid"></span></h5> 
<input type="hidden" name="delidd" id="delid_value">
```

And in your JS, if I understood what you want to do :

```
$(".modal-body #delid").text(pd_del_id); // Here you put the product's ID in your span to show it to the user.
$(".modal-body #delid_value").val(pd_del_id); // Here you put the product's ID in your hidden field to send it with your form.
```

Now, your PHP :

```
$delid=isset($_POST['delidd']);
echo $delid;
```

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns either true or false if the variable is set or not.
The variable $_POST['delidd'] is set (the hidden field is always sent to your PHP).
If you want to get the value (your product's ID) :

```
if (!empty($_POST['delidd'])) {
// The value is not empty
   $delid = $_POST['delidd'];
} else {
// The value is empty : there is a problem (For example echo an error message or do whatever you have to do in that case.)
}
```

Comment: Not a man... ;) Don't forget to secure your code. A hidden field doesn't mean that your user can't change its value and put whatever he wants in it, so you'll have to check whether your $delid is an int or not, etc.